# Find out when OpenGL ES content is actually displayed on iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, eaglcontext

When using a EAGLContext with render buffer storage in a CAEAGLLayer, after calling presentRenderbuffer,

1) Is the appearance of the buffer synchronized with vertical screen refresh?
2) How can I get a timestamp for the start of the vertical scan containing the changes?